# PHP session variables stopped work

Tags: php, macos, session, mamp

I'm having problem with my session variables. Few days ago it was working. I'm on mamp 3.5 and php 7.0 (on a mac). My website is working fine it's only a computer problem.
On windows everything works but on my mac, when I login he create a session variable, but on the next page the session variable is empty.

On my friend's computer (on mac too) it didn't work...

Here's my login code :

```
<form method="post" action="connexion_prof.php" id="formulaire" name="formulaire" novalidate>
      <label for="Identifiant">Identifiant :</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="identifiant" name="identifiant" required data-validation-required-message="Entrer un identifiant.">

      <label for="Mdp">Mot de passe :</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="mdp" name="mdp" required data-validation-required-message="Entrer un mot de passe.">

      <input type="checkbox" name="cookie" id="cookie"/> <label for="cookie">Se souvenir de moi.</label>

      <input type="submit" id="connexion" name="Connexion" value="Connexion" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

And here's my connexion_prof.php code :

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root'); 
mysqli_select_db($db,'Projet') or die(mysqli_error());
```

And :

```
$sql = "select Password, Statut, Nom, Prenom, ID, Statut from User where Username='".$identifiant."'";
$req = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysqli_error());

$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req);
$_SESSION['Username'] = $identifiant;
$_SESSION['Nom'] = $data['Nom'];
$_SESSION['Prenom'] = $data['Prenom'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $data['ID'];
$_SESSION['Statut'] = $data['Statut'];
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Edited, I have added some code

Comment: Did you include `session_start();` at the start of all files?

Comment: Yes it's included in all file in the header, even if it's not used. On my other computer (windows) everything works fine. It's only on my mac

Answer (score 0):

I could also see there being a configuration difference in the PHP.ini files you use identifiers to get the post request parameters (i.e $identifiant) rather than the PHP global $_POST array, try changing that using $_POST['identifiant'] and see if this fixes your issue; unless you've manually created these variables they are not set but PHP does allow for a configuration in which the values are mapped to variables, that configuration is however disabled by default.

Let me know if this fixes the issue